# Regex match a dynamic pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, regex-negation

Hey guys i got stuck with this problem:

I have this pattern:

(group1) ; (group2) ; (group3) ; ...
Actually i don't know how many groups the rows can have and i need to match all groups between `\s;\s`.

I was thinking about a negative of pattern `^(!?\s;\s)` but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing a string split in this case, which also handles nicely the problem of not knowing how many groups you have, e.g.

```js
var input = "group 1 ; group 2 ; group 3";
var groups = input.split(/\s*;\s*/);
console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [example](https://regex101.com/r/aqzhnB/1)

```
([^\s;]{3,})  // made use of negation approch
```